# T-SQL Convert Comma Delimited column into multiple columns - Dynamic

Tags: sql-server, csv, dynamic, multiple-columns, common-table-expression

SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a table with a `varchar` column which contains a comma delimited string. The number of comma delimited fields can vary in number, from only a couple of them up to several dozen (50+). I need to convert the CSV string into columns. An example of the table data:

```
DECLARE @tv_Table1 TABLE 
                   (
                       Name VARCHAR(MAX),
                       [Values] VARCHAR(MAX)
                   );

INSERT INTO @tv_Table1 
VALUES ('Number1', '00,1110801100543 20190801103956,123456798708/01/201910:07:13,123456787608/01/201910:08:26,123456776508/01/201910:08:56,123456755508/01/201910:09:26,SOME TEXT1,123456744408/01/201910:29:08,'),
       ('Number2', 'val,val2,val3,'),
       ('Number3', 'val5,val7,val9,val14,'),
       ('Number4', '00,8980801100904 20190801128781,777333489808/01/201910:07:13,777333489808/01/201910:08:26,777333489808/01/201910:08:56,777333489808/01/201910:09:26,777333489808/01/201910:10:14,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:05:56,777333489808/01/201910:12:05,777333489808/01/201910:12:44,777333489808/01/201910:13:02,777333489808/01/201910:13:02,777333489808/01/201910:13:32,777333489808/01/201910:14:03,777333489808/01/201910:15:15,777333489808/01/201910:15:46,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:19:08,777333489808/01/201910:19:38,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:28:31,777333489808/01/201910:29:02,777333489808/01/201910:29:32,777333489808/01/201910:30:02,777333489808/01/201910:30:32,777333489808/01/201910:31:02,777333489808/01/201910:31:32,777333489808/01/201910:32:02,777333489808/01/201910:32:33,777333489808/01/201910:33:02,777333489808/01/201910:33:33,777333489808/01/201910:34:11,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:36:47,777333489808/01/201910:37:17,777333489808/01/201910:37:35,')

SELECT 
    Name,
    Commas = LEN([Values]) - LEN(REPLACE([Values], ',', '')),
    [Values]
FROM 
    @tv_Table1
```

[image: CSVs in a column]

The last character in the string I need to break into columns will always be a comma (,).

I need the output to look like this:

[image: Desired Output csv to columns]

I started down the path of using a CTE:

```
;WITH
L0 AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1 AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
L2 AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
L3 AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
Numbers AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS n FROM L3)
SELECT 
Name, 
[1] AS Column1, [2] AS Column2, [3] AS Column3, [4] AS Column4, [5] AS Column5, 
[6] AS Column6, [7] AS Column7,[8] AS Column8, [9] AS Column9, [10] AS Column10, 
[11] AS Column11, [12] AS Column12, [13] AS Column13, [14] AS Column14,[15] AS Column15
FROM
(SELECT Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY nums.n) AS PositionInList,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(valueTable.[Values], nums.n, charindex(N',', valueTable.[Values] + N',', nums.n) - nums.n))) AS [Value]
 FROM   Numbers AS nums INNER JOIN @tv_Table1 AS valueTable ON nums.n <= CONVERT(int, LEN(valueTable.[Values])) AND SUBSTRING(N',' + valueTable.[Values], n, 1) = N',') AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX([VALUE]) FOR PositionInList IN (
[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], 
[6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
[11], [12], [13], [14], [15]

)
) AS Table2
```

However, there were a couple problems with this.  One, it dawned on me that it wasn't dynamic (and the data can be); and Two, what I had thus far stopped at 11 (Number4 should have had 37 columns).

Is there a way to make this dynamic?  Is there a better way to go about this?  Is there a way to make what I have got thus far work?

Some restrictions I have - I cannot change the table structure. I cannot add functions.  I should be able to add a stored procedure if needed, but would prefer not to.

Any thoughts, assistance, suggestions, etc. appreciated.

The query will run on demand, usually for a single day, approx 500 rows, of these maybe a dozen will need to have the CSV string-to-columns.

Comment: there are many answers to this that use XML parsing to do the split -- have you done a google search?

Comment: And did you know that sql 2008 end of life was last month. Time to consider upgrading!!

Comment: The best option is to normalize your database and avoid this situation entirely. But sometimes we are stuck. Here are some excellent options for splitting strings. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Of course it also seems you are going to need a dynamic pivot or a dynamic cross tab. This is two challenging pieces of code in a single problem.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?   Just return the data in it's native format and let the consuming application handle the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temp table, you can construct a dynamic query. The temp table holds the parse raw data. Then get the max Position in the list, build the COlumns and Pivot Value using the max position.

```
DECLARE @tv_Table1 TABLE 
                   (
                       Name VARCHAR(MAX),
                       [Values] VARCHAR(MAX)
                   );

INSERT INTO @tv_Table1 
VALUES ('Number1', '00,1110801100543 20190801103956,123456798708/01/201910:07:13,123456787608/01/201910:08:26,123456776508/01/201910:08:56,123456755508/01/201910:09:26,SOME TEXT1,123456744408/01/201910:29:08,'),
       ('Number2', 'val,val2,val3,'),
       ('Number3', 'val5,val7,val9,val14,'),
       ('Number4', '00,8980801100904 20190801128781,777333489808/01/201910:07:13,777333489808/01/201910:08:26,777333489808/01/201910:08:56,777333489808/01/201910:09:26,777333489808/01/201910:10:14,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:05:56,777333489808/01/201910:12:05,777333489808/01/201910:12:44,777333489808/01/201910:13:02,777333489808/01/201910:13:02,777333489808/01/201910:13:32,777333489808/01/201910:14:03,777333489808/01/201910:15:15,777333489808/01/201910:15:46,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:19:08,777333489808/01/201910:19:38,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:28:31,777333489808/01/201910:29:02,777333489808/01/201910:29:32,777333489808/01/201910:30:02,777333489808/01/201910:30:32,777333489808/01/201910:31:02,777333489808/01/201910:31:32,777333489808/01/201910:32:02,777333489808/01/201910:32:33,777333489808/01/201910:33:02,777333489808/01/201910:33:33,777333489808/01/201910:34:11,SOME TEXT2,777333489808/01/201910:36:47,777333489808/01/201910:37:17,777333489808/01/201910:37:35,')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RawData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #RawData;
CREATE TABLE #RawData(
    Name varchar(max) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not null,
    PositionInList int not null,
    [Value] varchar(max) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not null
)

;WITH
L0 AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1 AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
L2 AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
L3 AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
Numbers AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS n FROM L3)
INSERT #RawData(Name,PositionInList,[Value])
SELECT Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY nums.n) AS PositionInList,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(valueTable.[Values], nums.n, charindex(N',', valueTable.[Values] + N',', nums.n) - nums.n))) AS [Value]
FROM   Numbers AS nums 
INNER JOIN @tv_Table1 AS valueTable 
ON nums.n <= CONVERT(int, LEN(valueTable.[Values])) 
AND SUBSTRING(N',' + valueTable.[Values], n, 1) = N','

-- SELECT * FROM #RawData;

DECLARE @MaxPos int;
DECLARE @Cols varchar(2048)='';
DECLARE @PvtVals varchar(2048)='';
DECLARE @i int=1;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)='';
SELECT @MaxPos = MAX(PositionInList) FROM #RawData;
WHILE @i<@MaxPos
BEGIN
    SET @Cols=@Cols+',['+CAST(@i AS varchar(20))+'] AS Column' + CAST(@i AS varchar(20))
    SET @PvtVals=@PvtVals+',['+CAST(@i AS varchar(20))+']'
    SET @i=@i+1;
END
SET @PvtVals=RIGHT(@PvtVals,LEN(@PvtVals)-1);

SET @SQL='
SELECT 
Name'+ @Cols +'
FROM #RawData
PIVOT
(
MAX([VALUE]) FOR PositionInList IN ('+@PvtVals+')
) AS Table2';
-- PRINT @SQL;
exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: This code  _almost_ gets me exactly what I need to have.  I did not state in the original question (at the time I was just trying to parse out a variable number of csv columns from a string), but what I needed to do is the first 2 positions (Column1 & Column2) needed to be a fixed name (like "StatusCode" and "PartInfo") with the numbering actually beginning with the 3rd column (i.e. StatusCode, PartInfo, Column1, Column2, Column3, etc.)  The last part I'm working on is getting this into an Excel Spreadsheet, but first things first.... :)

Comment: I ended up changing the CAST(@i as varchar(20)) to CAST(@i-2 as varchar(20)) and then doing a REPLACE for Column-1 and Column0 in the @SQL variable.  Worked like a charm...  Now just cleaning it up a little.  Thank you for your help PeterHe

Comment: thanks good solution, but is there any other option instead of one by one column read it will affect on performance